# Помогите написать код решения задачи на С++

Tags: c++, ряды

Вычислить значение S, для вычисления факториала использовать функцию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мои потуги написать код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int fact(int x) {
    if (x <= 1) return 1;
    else return x * fact(x - 1);
}

int main(void) {
    double a, d;
    int i;
    float s, m;
    s = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        m = 2;
        d = fact(pow(int(i), int(m)));
        a = float((pow(int(-1), int(i + 1))) / float(d));
        s = s + a;
    }
    printf("Result=%f\n", s);
}
```

Comment: Используйте double для вычисления факториала и всех промежуточных вычислений.. 100! это примерно 1.0e158, т.е.  int  будет переполняться. (float, тоже переполнится.)

Comment: Что не так с приведённым кодом?

Comment: @wchistow результат -none

Comment: @Chorkov можете, пожалуйста, показать где замену сделать?

Comment: @ДанилаМастер  `double fact(int x)` , и далее повсюду во всех определениях переменных и преобразованиях типов.

Comment: цикл в задаче начинался от нуля, у вас от единицы ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

double fact(int x) {
    if (x <= 1) return 1;
    else return x * fact(x - 1);
}

int main(void) {
    double a, d;
    int i;
    double s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        d = fact(i * i);
        a = pow(-1, i + 1) / d;
        s = s + a;
    }
    printf("Result=%f\n", s);
}
```

---

*Вывод:*

> `Result=-0.041664`

---

Нужно было использовать `double`, когда угрожает переполнение, и цикл начинать с нуля. Ваша переменная `m` не была нужна т.к. ee значение всегда `2`, и вместо `pow(int(i), int(m))` я просто написал `i * i`.

Comment: Оно понятно, что для 11 членов можно и так... но стоит ли каждый раз с нуля считать факториал или использовать `pow(-1, i + 1)`? Если простое `sign = -sign` слишком просто, то хотя бы `2*(i%2)-1` или там `((i&1)<<1)-1` :)

Comment: За `pow(-1, ...)` рука к минусу тянется...

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Данила, не стоит.:-)